# How to join a database user to the db_owner role using a T-SQL script?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008r2-express

I use SQL SERVER 2008 R2 Express.

I'm on a NEW project with a database named `myDatabase` with the db owner username `myUsernamae`.

I would like to use `ALTER ROLE` instead of `sp_addrolemember` due to this message from Microsoft regarding sp_addrolemember (Transact-SQL):

> Important This feature will be removed in a future version of
>   Microsoft SQL Server. Avoid using this feature in new development
>   work, and plan to modify applications that currently use this feature.
>   Use ALTER ROLE instead.

I tried

```
USE [myDatabase]
GO

ALTER ROLE [db_owner] ADD MEMBER [myUsername]
GO
```

but I keep getting this error message:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ADD'.

What is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`ALTER ROLE` is new to SQL Server 2012, while you are using SQL Server 2008 R2.

I wouldn't worry to much about `sp_addrolemember`.  Scripts generated by 2008R2 Management Studio use this procedure, so it should be a while before they really phase it out.